# Arquitetura Laravel para sistemas SaaS

Tags: php, laravel, arquitetura-de-software, multi-tenancy, saas

Eu estou fazendo um sistema em Laravel, porém esse sistema atenderá a vários usuários, e esses usuários poderam cadastrar seus clientes.

A grande questão é, para que não fique tudo em um único banco de dados, eu pensei em cada vez que o usuário se cadastrar na aplicação, criar um banco de dados novo, e dentro desse banco rodar as migrations das tabelas.

Porém cada usuário, poderá cadastrar seus clientes e esses clientes terão usuário e senha, no login eu teria que passar banco a banco para saber qual banco está aquele cliente para fazer a autenticação... então ja não achei uma prática legal, outra opção é pedir um identificador quando for logar, mas não acho que seria uma boa prática também.

A última opção é criar um banco único com todos os dados, so que as tabelas ficariam gigantes...

Algum arquiteto poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você pode usar uma tabela chamada **Rede** aonde essa rede é referenciado em todas as outras tabelas ou senha, usuarioRede e nela teria o id da rede e o id do usuario, assim nao ficaria tabelas gigantes

Answer (score 2):

Esse seu sistema parece ser um [SaaS (Software as a Service)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o), que é uma forma de distribuição de software onde os sistemas são acessíveis a partir de vários dispositivos por meio de uma interface cliente em uma rede de modelo cliente-servidor como um navegador Web. No SaaS, o usuário não administra as características individuais da aplicação, exceto configurações específicas para seu ambiente.

Identificam-se estes projetos como sistemas multi tenant (de vários inquilinos). Existem várias abordagens que tratam do modelo de banco de dados e até mesmo da existência de subdomínios por cliente (usuário) da aplicação.

Falando especificamente de banco de dados e considerando uma única base de código do sistema (instalação), resumidamente:

1. Na abordagem onde todos os usuários estão em um único banco de dados, é necessário que cada tabela de dados tenha o relacionamento com a chave primária correta do usuário owner (proprietário), e o cuidado de que toda manipulação e acesso aos dados seja realizado apenas aos registros que o owner possui. Vantagem está na arquitetura e manutenção, pois apenas uma atualização de banco de dados é necessária em alterações. Quanto ao volume de dados, se bem modelado e implementado, o banco terá a performance necessária.
2. Na abordagem de um banco de dados por tenant (inquilino), o sistema pode acessar todos os dados sem preocupação em validar os acessos aos registros de usuários owner apenas. Desvantagens, a infraestrutura é mais complexa, a cada atualização de banco de dados é necessário um esforço de tenant X bd, além de um banco de dados centralizado para a gerência dos usuários e os acessos aos bds corretos. Ou usar a estratégia de "escolha" de empresa em uma tela de login. Ou se utilizar subdomínios, controlar no bd central apenas o acesso ao banco correto. Ou ainda padronizar o nome e acesso aos bds de acordo com o nome do subdomínio.

Se pensar em uma plataforma de várias instalações, uma por usuário, teria a complexidade do item 2 acima, mais a de manter a atualização sincronizada de cada instalação de código fonte em manutenções.

Tratando-se de Laravel, eu tenho uma experiência maior com SaaS de um único banco e funciona bem. Meu sistema utiliza o pacote https://github.com/nunomazer/laravel-samehouse. Mas existem outros pacotes excelentes que dão suporte a ambas as estratégia, são eles:

- Laravel Same House - https://github.com/nunomazer/laravel-samehouse
- Laravel Tenancy (antigo Hyn Tenancy) - https://tenancy.dev/
- Spatie Laravel Multitenancy - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy
- Tenancy for Laravel - https://tenancyforlaravel.com/

Answer (score -1):

Tenho um cenário parecido, porém no meu caso, eu possuo uma base de dados "clube", onde possui seus dados de login e os dados de acesso ao banco de dados de cada um, logo quando efetua login, eu realizo a busca dentro da base de dados clube, e então ao encontrar, pego os dados para acesso a base de dados própria, onde nela contém os dados de usuários específicos daquele clube.